# AdMob Ads don't load when the app is reopened

Tags: android, admob

I made a test app for trying out AdMob Ad implementation. The app loads the ads on the first go but when I close the app and reopen it, the ads don't load up, sometimes the ads don't load up when the device is connected to WiFi but load up when I switch to Cellular Data. In order to fix the first problem I 'Force Stop' the app or reboot the device. I'm using Banner Ads.

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        runnable.run()
    }
private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            AdView adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);

            AdView adView2 = findViewById(R.id.adView2);
            adView2.loadAd(adRequest);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            handler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from AdMob console > Ad Unit > `Advanced settings` > set `Automatic refresh` > to `Google optimized`

[image: adunit]